# Chrome extension json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm using Chrome Extension to change a sites CSS/javascript.

I'm looking to manipulate the layout and get data.

Inspecting the code on the website I can see it has a json file, similar to the below:

```
< form id='preference' data-json={'name':'test','age':'40'},{'name':'test','age':'30'},{'name':'test','age':'50'} >
```

How would I loop through the information in the JSON file?

Comment: Where is the json file?

Comment: "Similar to the one below," I dont think you pasted that code.

Comment: `similar to the below:` You forgot to include anything.

Comment: Sorry 

<form id="preference" json-date={'name':'test','age':'4'0'},{'name':'test','age':'4'0'},{'name':'test','age':'4'0'}>

Comment: that's not a _file_, it's a HTML element with a data-attribute containing some **invalid** JSON. So extract it from the attribute, add some array brackets `[` and `]` to either end of the string to make it an array instead of a disconnected list of objects, and then convert all the single-quotes to double-quotes to make it valid JSON, and then convert it to a JS array using JSON.parse and then treat it like any other JS array

Comment: Thanks, please could you give me an example of the code used to extract and parse, im new to this,

Comment: any JS tutorial will show you how to get an element, how to get an attribute from an element. The only hard part might be replacing the values in the string and appending them, but again you can get the syntax and examples of all the string-related commands from MDN, W3Schools and all those kind of sites. You can check the validity of your resulting JSON string at https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: @Lee The example you show isn't valid JSON and not even well-formed HTML.

Comment: And lastly you can you can also google the JSON.parse command, and find lots of examples of how to make loops and get the properties of an object. Have a go at it, it you get stuck with a specific thing ask us again. You'll learn a lot more by doing than just getting another example which re-invents the wheel of everything already available online. If you break the problem down into small enough steps like I have above, each part on its own becomes very researchable and very solvable.

Comment: P.S. phuzi makes a good point, that HTML is dodgy as well - the information in the data-json attribute should be enclosed in quotes itself. Is that really the exact content of the site you're looking at?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a JSON like this or you convert your data like the format below:

```
var data =   [{
        "name": "test",
        "age": "40"
    }, {
        "name": "test",
        "age": "30"
    }, {
        "name": "test",
        "age": "20"
    }]
```

As you are asking, how to loop through JSON. Follow this:

```
data.forEach(function(d){
                console.log("Name: " + d.name);
                console.log("Age: " + d.age);
            });
```